# How to Set Description in GitHub Hub Release Creation

Tags: github, automation

I know how to set the the title of the release by doing

```
hub release create -m "v1.0.0 Release" v1.0.0
```

But, how do I set the description? I've tried `hub release create -m "v1.0.0 Release\nThis is the description"` but the \n and the description still all go in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to do two messages like this:

```
hub release create -m "v1.0.0 Release" -m "This is the description for this release" v1.0.0
```